# custom us regions by zipcode using [r] geographic maps

Tags: r, maps, regions

The company I work for has its own special regions of the US for comparing sales. I'd like to be able to use such R packages as maps, mapdata and maptools but using these custom regions, each of which is defined by sets of zip codes. Is there a package with a function that would allow me to define those custom regions by assigning a set of zip codes to a name for each of the custom regions?

This looked promising at first but it doesn't create custom regions:
([how do I map (on a geographical map) data in R just given the US Zipcodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858533/how-do-i-map-on-a-geographical-map-data-in-r-just-given-the-us-zipcodes))

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'm not aware of such a function. However, you could write one. I'm sure you'll find a shape file with the zip data, and there are plenty of examples on how to merge polygons (i.e. zip areas).

Comment: "...plenty of examples on how to merge polygons"?! That would be exactly what is needed. Is this the place to start?  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/maptools/vignettes/combine_maptools.pdf

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=r+merge+polygons

Comment: This example might help as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847671/remove-us-state-borders-create-outlined-regions-in-ggplot2-geom-polygon/31855133#31855133