# How to create a map with zipcode dataset? ( US Zipcode )

Tags: r, maps, pdf-generation, zipcode

> How to create a map in R with zipcode dataset?

`data <- c("22313","10100","25001")` [example zipcode]

***In this moment, I have a dataset full of zipcode and I would like to print in a map and save it in pdf.***

***Best regards,***

***E.P.***

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get the shapefiles from?.. You didn't get any shapefiles, did you?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+zipcode+map

Comment: I get a dataset from Kaggle, and I would like to create a maps with the zipcode. I used the "maps" package but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I map (on a geographical map) data in R just given the US Zipcodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858533/how-do-i-map-on-a-geographical-map-data-in-r-just-given-the-us-zipcodes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code which I modified from January at [how do I map (on a geographical map) data in R just given the US Zipcodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858533/how-do-i-map-on-a-geographical-map-data-in-r-just-given-the-us-zipcodes):

```
pdf("myzipcodes.pdf")
library(maps)
map(database="usa")# national boundaries

library(zipcode)
data("zipcode")
myzips <- c("22313","83701","32301")
selected <- zipcode[ zipcode$zip %in% myzips, ]
points( selected$longitude, selected$latitude, pch= 19, cex= 2 )
text( selected$longitude, selected$latitude, selected$zip, pos=3, cex= 2 )
dev.off()
```

You provided two phony zip codes so I added a couple real ones.

In RStudio you can also export a plot as a PDF file using the 'export' menu.